# can not get the oil plug out

Tags: oil, chrysler, town-and-country

I was going to change my oil on a 2000 Chrysler Town and Country van. When I loosen the plug it just keep turning and turning, and I can not get it out. So is it stripped out and if it is, how do I remove it?

Answer (score 1):

If you can tighten it, there are some threads there which are gripping, so this would probably be a case of the threads on the plug being stripped. If it doesn't tighten back up,  this would probably be a case of either the threads on the pan or on the plug being stripped. I don't have any real good news for you here in either case, but could possibly help you to get the plug out in either.

What you'll need is the wrench or socket/ratchet you were using to loosen the plug, plus a fairly broad flat tip screwdriver. Loosen the plug so you have a gap between the pan and the plug head. Place the flat of the screwdriver between the pan and the plug head. While continuing to unscrew the bolt with the wrench or socket, turn the screwdriver with a bit of force, whatever is needed to keep the bolt coming out. Once the bolt starts biting again and continues to come out, you can stop applying force with the screwdriver. If it appears to be stalled again at any point, put the screwdriver back in there an apply some more pressure. This should allow you to get it out and assess the damage.

With all of this said, you are going to have a major problem if the issue lies in the pan ... I mean if you don't have the means with which to fix the issue. If you do not have the means, take it to a shop and have them fix it. The actual fix depends on how much damage actually has occurred. Also, if you have an aluminum oil pan, this adds a whole new dimension to the mix (I'm pretty sure the T&C has a steel pan, but not sure). In most cases, you will have damage on both the bolt and the pan. Replacing the bolt is easy ... fixing the threads in the pan may not be. Just be aware it is going to cost a few dollars to get it fixed, depending on the damage.